# Mark point of interest in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

My project's goal is to detect the lung's nodules , after filtering and classification i got a binary image like this:
[image]

my problem is i don't know how to mark these points of interest on the original image . In matlab ,i can do it easily with [hold on-off] a loop and some plot() function . But how do i do that in C++ , i don't mean to translate matlab code to C++ , i just need to mark these PoIs on the original image by any mean necessary .
Here is the result i want :
[image] 
 i did it in Matlab

EDIT : I already have the points's positions from my program (as you can see in the first image) all i want to do is draw them on the original image like the second one.

Comment: You'd need a library to get your started. Try OpenCV, it is an image processing library.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV , but i don't know how to mark these PoIs , that's the problem

Comment: What do you expect the image to look like after you've marked the points of interest? I might be able to suggest something if I know what you're trying to achieve, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "mark these points of interest".

Comment: here is the result i want,i did it in matlab [link](http://imgur.com/pePwpaI)

Comment: you mean you want to click on an image location and get the pixel coordinates of that location? you can use openCV callback functions, but if you want to develop a real program (insteadof a testing tool) you should use some real gui library like qt

Comment: @Micka i did some search and OpenCV callback function is great but it's not what i want here, why click if you don't know where to click , i just want to mark these points for better visualization ,like drawing of highlight or whatever.

Comment: with the mouse callback function you click on a position. then the callback function is called and you can programmatically use that pixel location.

Comment: or do you already know the point positions from your program and you just want to draw them? your question isnt completely clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

from your binary image you can extract contours.
Then either draw the contours directly, or extract bounding circles that cover the whole contour.

I'll present both methods.

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/markMatlab.png");

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    cv::Mat binaryImage = gray>0;
    cv::imshow("binary image", binaryImage);
    // here you start

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(binaryImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // either this:
    cv::Mat inputBlobs = input.clone(); // create output image
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Point2f blobCenter;
        float blobRadius;
        cv::minEnclosingCircle(contours[i], blobCenter, blobRadius);

        cv::circle(inputBlobs, blobCenter, blobRadius, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
    }

    // or this one:
    cv::Mat inputContours = input.clone();  // create output image
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::drawContours(inputContours, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2);
    }






    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("input blobs", inputBlobs);
    cv::imshow("input contours", inputContours);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/markMatlab.png", input);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/markMatlabBlobs.png", inputBlobs);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/markMatlabContours.png", inputContours);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

bounding circles:

[image]

drawing contours directly:

[image]

just use your original image as input for the drawing functions.

Comment: it's worked !! I didn't know about this approach. Thanks for enlighting me so much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Mat image;
image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

And then using [ellipse](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse) on it?

On maybe, if you do not know the coordinates, but you just have the resulting filtered image using [blend](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html)